# Filtering collection of sales/order model

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sales-order

I want collection of orders which belongs from customer_group_id = 4 or customer_group_id = 5. 
I have applied following filter on collection.

```
->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getGroupId())
```

This will filter the current user's customer_group_id with database's customer_group_id.

But what i want is, I want to filter on customers those who has customer_group_id equal to either '4' or '5'.

My question is, How should i apply this addAttributeToFilter to achieve that collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter order collection then,you need to

use `addFieldToFilter('filterablecolumn','filtertableCondition')`

and as you want collection filter `by two group_id ids then need use in array` in collection.

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('field_name', array(
    'in' => array('Val1','Val2','Val2'),
```

**Then try this:**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array(
        'in' => array(5,6);
```

**Or:**

```
 $collection=Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
 $collection->getSelect()->where('customer_group_id = ?', 4);
 echo $collection->getSelect()->orWhere('customer_group_id = ?', 5);
```

See how to [use collection filter in magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)

**EDIT**

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the answer amit. But here is one more twist. {->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getGroupId())  } here what i am doing is .. checking customer_group_id from session. What i want is. whatever i am gettting from "Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getGroupId()" should be equal to 5 or 6.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below piece of code to get the customer collection belongs to customer group 4 or 5.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
$collection->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("(e.group_id = 4 OR e.group_id = 5)"));
```

or

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(2, 4)));
```

Comment: I'm sure it works, but using magentos variety on filters helps to avoids SQL injection vulnerabilities http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento#filter_condition_codes

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I have added the code which is more Magento suited.